# Lua function selector

Tags: function, random, lua, selector

I have 3 functions. When the user presses the 'E' key I want it to select one of the functions (at random), I feel like it has something to do with `math.random` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with `math.random`. Post what your current code.

Comment: I haven't made the functions yet, but there will be 3 function that all do separate things, here's the function that is suppose to pick it at random:

http://pastebin.com/n9Ur2ig6

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't post your exact code if it's complecated. Post at most several dozens of lines of code that express your idea.

Comment: All I need to know is how I make a math.random statement to select a function...You shouldn't need to see my code for that, just give me a example of how its done, then I can put it so it works with my code

Comment: Let me say it like this, Stack Overflow is not a place where people write code for you. Instead, show what you have tried, and how it doesn't work. Then people can help you with the specific problem in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `math.random` to select a function; you use it to pick a random number, which you can then use as an index to get the function you need from a table (as one example):

```
local list = { function() print(1) end, function() print(2) end, function() print(3) end }
math.randomseed(os.time()) -- don't forget to seed or you likely to get the same sequence
for i = 1, 10 do list[math.random(#list)]() end
```